# Test that a nested function is called in a void method with moq

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core, dependency-injection, moq

I have an implementation of an interface and want to cover the methods in the implementation.  Most of the functions are void and do one thing and I want to test that a certain call is made but not sure exactly how to do it with mock

FakeService.cs

```
public FakeService(IRepository<FaketTable> repo)

public virtual void ClearAll()
{
 this.fakeTablerepo.Truncate();
}
```

I want to write a test to make sure Truncate was called. There is nothing returned so there is nothing to assert on.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assert that the desired member was called/invoked

```
[TestMethod]
public void ClearAll_Should_Truncate_Repo() {    
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IRepository<FaketTable>>();

    var subject = new FakeService(mock.Object);

    //Arrange
    subject.ClearAll();

    //Assert
    mock.Verify(_ => _.Truncate(), Times.Once());
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework